# Block direct IP connections to Apache web server

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, ip, block

I need to figure out how to block direct IP access to my website.

Example: I want it so that when people type my IP address `1.2.3.4` into the browser it doesn't work, but when they type `www.example.com` it does work.

I am using `Apache 2.4.9`, and my website is run using `WampServer`.

I have tried other solutions from some old questions on here, but none of them have worked for me. I have tried pasting virtual host stuff into the vhosts.conf, but I couldn't get it right, and I tried doing rewrite stuff with the htaccess file, but that didn't work either.

Comment: The duplicate question is not quite the same, but the answer works for your situation as well.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the first virtual host entry also acts as the default, so make your first virtual host entry point to a folder with an access denied page.

Comment: In addition to preventing use of the default virtual host for any other purpose (_if_ a user should have one), this approach also prevents serving localized error pages to the browser accessing by IP address

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to set a rewrite condition within the global server context that disallows IP based requests by requiring an HTTP header similar to
the example shown below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error [NC]
RewriteRule ^.(.*) - [L,F]
```

NOTE: This example requires that you enable `mod_rewrite`.

NOTE ALSO: If you have multiple virtual hosts, you can modify the `RewriteCond` to check more broadly or use multiple `RewriteCond` statements to accommodate the different domains.

An alternative configuration is:

```
<If req('Host') != 'www.example.com'">
  <Location "/">
    Require all denied
  </Location>
</If>
```

Comment: This just gave me a error on all my web pages when visiting anything.
I think I have mod_rewrite enabled. I am very confused. I am a noob at apache.

Comment: It is hard to know why without digging through all of your configuration files, but added an alternative configuration that can work if inserted in the right place.